# Internal depencencies declaration in multimodule project

Tags: maven, multi-module

I am working on a project with the following maven architecture:

- parent (pom)

  - module A (pom)

    - submodule A1 (jar)
    - submodule A2 (jar)
  - module B (pom)

    - submodule B1 (jar)
    - submodule B2 (jar)

The parent pom has a `dependencyManagement` section declaring the version of **external** dependencies.

Now how should I declare **internal** dependencies?

B2 has a dependency on B1 and A2. A2 has a dependency on A1.

My options are:

1. add the dependency with version

```
<!-- Submodule B2 -->
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>submoduleA2</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  [...]
</dependencies>
```

2. add all submodules (A1, A2, B1, B2) to the `dependencyManagement` of the parent pom with their version then add dependencies without version in the submodules :

```
<!-- Parent -->
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>submoduleA2</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<!-- Submodule B2 -->
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>submoduleA2</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  [...]
</dependencies>
```

3. add dependencies between modules through their dependencyManagement :

```
<!-- Module A -->
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>submoduleA2</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<!-- Module B -->
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<!-- Submodule B2 -->
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>submoduleA2</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  [...]
</dependencies>
```

4. other options ?

Answer (score 1):

The first option is applied often and usually fine.

Comment: Apache has opted for the second solution

Comment: That will also work, it is more or less a matter of taste and what you find easier to read/maintain.